# Table column styled with tailwindcss has wrong width in chrome and the correct in firefox

Tags: css, tailwind-css

In the following html snippet, using tailwindcss column widths work in firefox, but not in chrome. Chrome renders it all overlapped. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Columns should have minimal width and they should not overlap. I suspect one of the parents might have an issues with width, but then again, why would it work in firefox if it was wrong...

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-7 h-lvh">
    <main class="col-span-7 p-5 overflow-hidden bg-gray-100">
        <div class="flex flex-col h-full">
            
            <div class="overflow-scroll mt-5 rounded bg-white border border-gray-200">
                <table class="table-fixed w-full">
                    <thead class="text-md uppercase sticky top-0 bg-white">
                        <tr class="border-b">
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-24">
                                #
                            </th>

                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="p-3 w-max min-w-48 text-left">
                                Product name
                            </th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody class="overflow-y-scroll">
                        <tr class="border-b">
                            <th scope="row" class="px-3 py-1">
                                {index+1}
                            </th>

                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-3 py-1">
                                Apple MacBook Pro 17"
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `table-layout: fixed` is it not take the value of `min-width` into calculation on chrome. So either you set `width` for each `th` or you calculate the overall `min-width` for table base on how many columns it may get.